# python fix standalone exe created by py2exe including pyd/dll

Tags: glob, loadlibrary

I have a pretty simple script and I converted it to `exe` format with `py2exe`. I then moved it to a Windows 7 machine that doesn't have Python.

When I run it I get the following error:

> LoadLibrary(pythondll) failed
>   The specified module could not be found. C:\PYTHON27.DLL

I tried to read and test some code of including dll but nothing had worked. How can I include this dll?

If it helps, my python script just import basic stuff as

```
import os 
import getpass
import urllib2
import os
import re
import time
```

Comment: I believe you still need python to run the exe.

Comment: maybe i can include the python27.dll? all docs i saw are about including windows stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to distribute the DLL in the same directory as your executable, or put it in the environment PATH on the machine where you want to run the executable.

Comment: so there is no option to combine all in 1 exe? ):

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by having both 32 bit and 64 bit Python installed and on the path.

Look closely at the output from `python setup.py py2exe`

```
. . .
*** copy extensions ***
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_ssl.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\PythonEnvs\some_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-win32.egg\pyodbc.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\PythonEnvs\some_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\win32\win32print.pyd -> C:\path\to\project\dist
*** copy dlls ***
copying C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll -> C:\path\to\project\dist
setting sys.winver for 'C:\path\to\project\dist\python27.dll' to 'ProjectNameHere'
copying C:\PythonEnvs\some_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes27.dll -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll -> C:\path\to\project\dist
copying C:\PythonEnvs\some_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.6.9-py2.7-win32.egg\py2exe\run.exe -> C:\path\to\project\dist\mlr_startup.exe
```

Make sure py2exe is only pulling from the places you want.

In the functioning example above, py2exe is pulling in from the system install of Python 2.7, `C:\Python27`. It is also pulling in from the current virtual environment, `C:\PythonEnvs\some_virtualenv\lib\site-packages`. This results in a working executable.

When I was having this problem, I was seeing that py2exe was also pulling in things from other places, which had incompatible versions of Python.

For example, I had the 32 bit official Python, and then installed the 64 bit version of Mercurial. Mercurial installed its own 64 bit version of Python, and py2exe was pulling in a mix of 32 bit and 64 bit executables from `C:\Python27` and from `C:\Program Files\Mercurial\Python27`.

To resolve it, I just uninstalled Mercurial. Or, you could modify the Python path so that py2exe doesn't know about the Mercurial-installed version of Python, or any other undesirable installs of Python.